# Redux: Syncing backend DB with frontend app state tree

Tags: redux

From my experience, keeping backend DB and the frontend state tree in sync becomes a non-trivial task as the app grows more complicated.

For example, when you create a new `Post` in a blog, you have to create an object in the DB as well as attach a `post` object in your state tree (ex. inside posts reducer). It gets more complicated if the state tree is nested. If you update a comment that belongs to a post, you have to find the right post in the state tree, and find the right comment and update.

I understand why having an *App State Tree* is beneficial but this syncing causes too much overhead for me to truly appreciate Redux.

**Q.** Is there a way to do this syncing more easily?

Comment: Side Note: Meteor solves this problem by having a `client-side MongoDB` that automatically syncs with the backend for every action so this didn't feel painful at all. In Redux, for every resource (e.g. post) I have to think about how to update the tree for every action (CRUD). Is this what everyone is doing, and still fine with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor is specifically designed to solve the problem you're mentioning.

Redux is only to manage state on the client. More precisely, its job is to hold the state needed for the ui itself.

It's often used with React where it functions as a smart place to stash anything and everything needed to render the ui. This often includes a complicated state and may include a lot of app data. It may then start to look more like a database, but databases have a number of properties that Redux lacks. Persistence comes to mind...

Meteor is a framework and Redux is not. As such, Meteor comes with an enormous amount of buy-in where Meteor decides on how to deal with a large number of issues in your app. Redux on the other hand is very permissive. It doesn't decide on what your state looks like, or how you talk to your backend, or how you render your ui.

So inasmuch as Redux allows you the freedom to decide for yourself how to deal with these issues, it also leaves you with the responsibility to do so. Redux is super tiny and you should only expect rock solid state management, and nothing more.

How much of your global app state you move to the client is entirely up to you, and how you connect it to your backend, and if this backend runs node.js+Mongo or php+mysql or lisp+text files is entirely up to you. The same can not be said when using Meteor.

With great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I guess "more responsibility" bothers me especially because I tend to focus on fast prototyping. In your experience, were there any tools to remove the repetitive work when working in Redux? (e.g. CRUD for every resource takes a long time, syncing data is burdensom, etc.)

Comment: I like using Redux Schema which is why I wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @DDS :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and I'm sure there's a tried-and-true correct response to this. However, I brainstormed two possible solutions:

1) add the post to the app state 'manually', then the next time a GET is requested, reconcile the state and the response (your strategy). This is a lot easier if your client state is [normalized](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

2) do a GET immediately after the POST status is 200, and deal with the latency with an activity indicator.

The accepted answer to me , is not a fundamental explanation.